# C# Web API Optional parameters in query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-get

I have this piece of code in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("team={team}&model={model}&date={date}&distance={distance}")]
public IHttpActionResult FindVehicle([FromUri]string team = "", [FromUri]string model = "", [FromUri]DateTime? date = null, [FromUri]double distance = 0.0)
    { }
```

All of the parameters of the query string can be optional, which is why I used the default values.

However, I am not sure what the route should be, since now, when I don't specify the `model` parameter for example, its value in the endpoint ends up being `"model"`, and not `""`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to define `FromUri` elements inside `Route` attribute, they will be bound out of the box:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("route_name")]
public IHttpActionResult FindVehicle([FromUri]string team = "", [FromUri]string model = "", [FromUri]DateTime? date = null, [FromUri]double distance = 0.0)
{ 

}
```

If you are using, ASP.Net Core, then you should use `[FromQuery]` instead

Comment: But you could for better transparency and code style?

Comment: @liqSTAR definitely that's an option, it comes down to the preference and defined style indeed. In my opinion decorating params with the same attribute adds noise to the method signature. I would use it only in situation when there are different sources to bind model from. (e.g. `ApiMethod([FromUri] string p1, [FromBody] string p2, [FromHeader] string p3)`)

Comment: How to pass string model as optional parameter here?