# What is the proper way to implement optional query paramters in asp.net core?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, optional-parameters

So I have a generic URL that is used in multiple places on my React app to send a call to my asp.net core api.
Now due to a change requrement, I need to use the same url but in one specific scenario, I need to send an additional query parameter.
I want to use the same url without affecting the current implementation.
Please suggest or direct me to the proper way in asp.net core to implement this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768429/c-sharp-web-api-optional-parameters-in-query-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asp.net mvc routing with multiple optional parameters did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582394/asp-net-mvc-routing-with-multiple-optional-parameters-did-not-work)

Comment: S.a. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#rtr

Comment: Thank you everyone,
@ChristophLütjen, I think this might help me with the concept and implementation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

About the optional query parameters in WebApi, the usual practice is to add `?`, but it can only correspond to the order of the parameters one-to-one.

```
    [Route("get/{a?}/{b?}")]
    public IActionResult get( string a, string b)
    {
        return Ok(new { a,b});
    }
```

If you use multiple `[Route]` to achieve the same purpose as above. It can match the corresponding value according to the data type.

```
    [Route("get/{a}")]
    [Route("get/{a}/{b}")]
    [Route("get/{b:int}")]
    public IActionResult get( string a, int b)
    {
        return Ok(new { a,b});
    }
```

About other rules, you can refer to the document which Christoph Lütjen provided in comment.

Comment: what about reactjs, is there someway to add an optional parameter there aswell?